# Treating wood knots before oiling wooden floor

Tags: hardwood-floor

I have sanded my floor down and am ready to finish it with an [oil](https://www.osmouk.com/sitechapter.cfm?chapter=82&page=247#PolyxOil). Should I be treating the knots in the wood before finishing with the oil, or is it not required?

I have read somewhere that you shouldn't need to treat the knots if you plan to finish with an oil based product, but there was no real rationale or justification for the statement.

Answer (score 0):

I have refinished and installed several wood floors using oil finishes and have never treated any knots but most of the floors were close to clear. I would say NO treatment is necessary unless you have a unique flooring type.

Comment: Thanks for that. They are just standard floorboards